# How to make a text-box for writing answer using jquery in a webpage?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, html.textboxfor

I am making a question-answer forum website. For that i need one text-box for writing answer, having features like **BOLD**, *Italic* ,Bullets,insert image and add link. eg. answer box in [Quora](https://www.quora.com)

Comment: So what is the question

Comment: Please show some code that you have tried. If you want others to write full code for you, you should consider hiring a freelancer. Please take some time to visit the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help) and also read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), so you can learn what types of questions are accepted here, how to write questions, and how to use this site effectively

Comment: I am looking for an idea to make an answer text-box like quora.com. I would  have written the code in question if i had complete idea about  it. I am not expecting full code solution.